# recognizing gesture in iOS

Tags: ios

who knows which would be the following gesture:
Imagine I click within some region (say a button), I hold the finger down,
don't release it, and move the finger outside the region area??
is there some gesture to it?

I have a button which starts up in a selected/highlighted state, but if a user clicks
on it (using a finger), doesn't release his/her finger, moves his/her finger outside the button area, my button gets deselected - which is something I don't want. Can someone help?

Comment: There is no mouse on any device using iOS.

Comment: I was testing using a simulator that's why I mentioned mouse there

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle "Touch Up Outside" button event.

==EDIT==

You can override `UIControl`'s `*TrackingWithTouch:withEvent:` methods to get the behaviour you want:

```
@interface CustomButton : UIButton

@end
```

implementation

```
@interface CustomButton()

// Auxiliary property
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL isHighlightedBeforeTouch;

@end

@implementation CustomButton

-(BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  self.isHighlightedBeforeTouch = self.highlighted;
  return [super beginTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];
}

-(BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  BOOL result = [super continueTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];
  if( self.isHighlightedBeforeTouch && !CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, [touch locationInView:self]) ) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      self.highlighted = self.isHighlightedBeforeTouch;
    });
  }
  return result;
}

-(void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.highlighted = self.isHighlightedBeforeTouch;
  });
  [super endTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

to change highlighted property e.g. on when button is pressed:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [sender setHighlighted:![sender isHighlighted]];
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks. I modified my post, do you think your advice will also work in this case? ps. I am getting an exception thrown when I add a TouchUpOutside method, what could be wrong??? Thanks.
`
    [myBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(myActionMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
    

-(void) myActionMethod
{

    NSLog(@"tapped outside");
}`

Comment: use @selector(myActionMethod) or change action method to -(void)myActionMethod:(id)sender {...}

Comment: Hi, it solved the exception problem but selection/deselection still doesn't work properly (please see my updated post). Thanks

Comment: Probably you mean not selected nut highlighted state of button?

Comment: Yes, maybe highlighted; something I set using these properties for instance:  btn.highlighted = YES; btn.selected = YES;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use, UIGesuture recongnizers: UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Hi thanks. I will check it but do you know also one thing? If I override following method: [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(myActionMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside]; and try to set a selected state of the button inside it, it doesn't work -- do you have any idea why?? Thanks. any help appreciated. i.e., -(void) myActionMethod { btn.highlighted = YES; btn.selected = YES; }